# modify name of files in a directory

Tags: perl

I need to modify part of the name of files in a directory, I use the following code, but it only prints in terminal the modification of string but not save it

```
my @files = glob("*.grb *.out");
foreach my $file (@files) {
    print "$file\n";
    s/d02/d03/g;
}
```

How can I get them with the string d03 instead ofg d02?

Comment: The above code does not print the modified filename to terminal.  You're printing it first, and then you're doing a substitution on an uninitialized value (the `$_` variable).  

Please paste the code you actually tried, that represents your best attempt at solving the problem.

Comment: See [rename](http://p3rl.org/rename).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
my @files = glob("*.grb *.out");
foreach my $file (@files) {
    (my $newName = $file) =~ s/d02/d03/g;
    rename $file, $newName;
}
```

Or if you have Perl 5.14+,

```
my @files = glob("*.grb *.out");
foreach my $file (@files) {
    my $newName = $file =~ s/d02/d03/gr;
    rename $file, $newName;
}
```

This will rename all `*d02*` files to `*d03*` files (on-disk).

Comment: Thanks @ikegami for the supplement. I'm still not used to the `/r`. Ahhrg. And I used CamelCase. Shame on me. Sorry for that.